# Unable to unpack a TAR file, "Cannot Change Ownership To UID 65534"

Tags: pi-3

I'm trying to install wordpress to a USB stick on a RP3.

I've downloaded the latest version using the following command in to my USB directory:

```
sudo wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

I then try to unpack it using:

```
sudo tar xzf latest.tar.gz
```

But I get the following output:

```
tar: wordpress/wp-config-sample.php: Cannot change ownership to uid 65534, gid 65534: Operation not permitted
tar: wordpress: Cannot change ownership to uid 65534, gid 65534: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I have set the directory's ownership using the `chown` command and know that that's OK.

Am I missing something? I'm following the guide here [Guide To Install Wordpress On Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/worksheet/)

Comment: How is the USB stick formatted?

Comment: FAT32, however I have realised that the stick isn't "mounted", not sure if it needs to be?

Comment: I suspect you want `sudo tar --no-same-owner xzf latest.tar.gz`. When run as `uid=0`, `tar` doesn't default to extract files as yourself. If the `pi` (I haven't checked) limits the `uid/gid` to less than `65534`, you are trying to extract as a user/group that cannot be created.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that FAT **does not support** users, or any other Linux attributes or permissions. The best it can do is inherit the permissions of the mount point. **OBVIOUSLY** the drive needs to be mounted!

I am not sure if it even makes sense to try to extract Wordpress files to FAT. AFAIK these are just `php` and `js` so probably nothing special is required. I don't currently have easy access to a Wordpress installation.

Comment: I'm extremely new to this, anything obvious is not obvious to me

Comment: @SilverShotBee In which case you would be better installing Wordpress (and presumably LAMP) on your SD Card, the way it is intended.

Comment: I at least need to get the uploads on the ssd as there will be multiple videos exceeding 2GB and the SD card will not be future proof as it fills up. A 1TB SSD is Les likely to be filled in the next couple of years.

Comment: @SilverShotBee If you wish to use an external drive as a drive for software and not just data file storage , you should reformat your drive from FAT to EXT4 and call it a day, however this drive will not be compatible with Windows and Apple computers without additional drivers.

Comment: You can also consider using the ssd as a mount point for video files only and leave the drive as is, I believe that wordpress has a way to change the storage path for videos. There are other limitations, FAT has a 4GB file size limit.